# Extension of USAMO 1993 problem 2

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles

'Given an orthodiagonal cyclic quadrilateral, where the intersection is $E$, prove that when $E$ is reflected through the $4$ sides, the four new points form a new cyclic quadrilateral with the same circumcentre as the original cyclic quadrilateral'.
I have managed to do the 'prove it is a cyclic quadrilateral' part but am stuck after that. I tried to use angles to prove that O will also be the centre of the new cyclic quadrilateral, but it seems messy and the new angles don't match up with the original ones so I find it hard to prove, e.g. that the angle subtended at the centre is twice that at the sides. Please help with the circumcentres part!! Thanks

Comment: @Kevin Long See please my post. These things Ginny Mothball Wong got already. He looks for the proof that two circles are concentric. See better Ginny Mothball Wong's words.

Answer (score 1):

Let $ABCD$ be our quadrilateral and $AC\cap BD=\{E\}$.

Also, let $P$, $Q$, $R$ and $S$ be reflections of $E$  through the sides $AB$, $BC$, $CD$ and $AD$ respectively and $K$, $L$, $M$ and $N$ be midpoints of $PE$, $QE$, $RE$ and $SE$ respectively.

Thus, $NK||PS$ and since $AKEN$ is cyclic, we obtain $$\measuredangle KAE=\measuredangle PSE.$$
By the same way we'll obtain:
$$\measuredangle EDC=\measuredangle ESR,$$
$$\measuredangle ABE=\measuredangle PQE$$ and
$$\measuredangle ECD=\measuredangle EQR.$$
Id est,
$$\measuredangle PSR+\measuredangle PQR=\measuredangle PSE+\measuredangle ESR+\measuredangle PQE+\measuredangle EQR=$$
$$=\measuredangle BAE+\measuredangle EDC+\measuredangle ABE+\measuredangle ECD=90^{\circ}+90^{\circ}=180^{\circ},$$
which gives that $PQRS$ is cyclic.

Comment: But OP says he's already proved $PQRS$ is cyclic.

Comment: @user263326 Just there are users, which wishes to close this topic and I posted the Ginny Mothball Wong's trying. See my first comment.